# Angular app broken because of a single line of code in Safari Only, Working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I'm not sure why the below piece of code broke the entire app in Safari browser.
The commented line of code broke the App on compile.

```
    if (history.selectedRegions) {
       for (var i = 0; i < history.selectedRegions.length; i++) {
       // vm.selectedRegions.push(vm.allRegion[vm.allRegion.map((el) => el.nameEng).indexOf(history.selectedRegions[i].nameEng)]);
       }
   }
```

Comment: `(el) => el.nameEng` seems to broke the safari. Try an es5 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try es5:

```
vm.selectedRegions.push(vm.allRegion[vm.allRegion.map(function (el) {
    return el.nameEng;
}).indexOf(history.selectedRegions[i].nameEng)]);
```